# Xamarin.Forms Image Not Displaying Despite Correct Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing an issue with displaying an Image in my Xamarin.Forms application. Despite following the correct configuration steps, the image is not showing. Here's a simplified version of my XAML and code-behind:

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackLayout x:Name="menuStack1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**C# Code-Behind:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Add();
}

private void Add()
{
    var image = new Image
    {
        Source = "YourNamespace.icon.png", // Replace YourNamespace with the namespace of your project
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
        HeightRequest = 50,
        WidthRequest = 50,
        AutomationId = "i"
    };

    // Add this line to check if the image exists
    Console.WriteLine($"Image file exists: {ImageSource.FromResource("YourNamespace.icon.png") != null}");

    image.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = new Command(() => Image_Tapped()) });
    menuStack1.Children.Add(image);
}

private void Image_Tapped()
{
    DisplayAlert("Image Tapped", "Image tapped", "OK");
}
```

I have verified that the image file is marked as an embedded resource, and the file path and namespace are correct. However, the image is not displayed. The Console.WriteLine statement in the code indicates that the image file is not found.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve it? Are there any additional steps I should take to ensure the image is loaded correctly?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which project is the image embedded in?  The docs have a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#troubleshoot-embedded-images) on debugging embedded images

Comment: @Jason Resources.

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Which **project’s** resources?

Comment: Main project ( not android not ios ).

Comment: most likely your resource id is wrong.  Follow the debug instructions in the docs to verify

Comment: Why dont you use ImageButton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to display images for your case,

### Option 1 Use [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)

This method is recommended when identical images are used on each platform, and is particularly suited to creating components, as the image is bundled with the code.

To use it, just place the image in the Main project like you did and set **Build Action** to **EmbeddedResource**.

Then use the following code to get the image source,

```
        var image = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Yournamespace.icon.png", typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly), // Replace YourNamespace with the namespace of your project
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
           ...
        };
```

### Option 2  Use [Local Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

For Android, please place the image in the Android project's **Resources/drawable** directory with **Build Action**: **AndroidResource**.

For iOS, either place the image in the iOS project's **Resources** directory with **Build Action**: **BundleResource** or use [Asset Catalog Image Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos).

For UWP - Images should be placed in the UWP project's root directory with **Build Action: Content**.

Then when you use this image, no need to use Namespace, just set,

```
var image = new Image
{
    Source = "icon.png", 
    ...
};
```

For more info, please refer to [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows)